# check multiple values in cell

Tags: vba, excel

THE VBA noob is back. I need some help with some basic stuff i suppose for u pros out there.

I have a range (column H) with values such as

```
P595349 saf XD    
P5933 LP XD    
P5955 GW1 (GG+W+P+E) XD
```

what i want is a formula or a VBA code that look if the cell contain 59 and PD it should print Correct in column E and if not it should print Not Correct in column E.

What i have today is only a start but i dont know how to add the second value (59) in this case.

```
  Sub AddDashes()

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

     Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

     Set SrchRng = Range("A:a")

     For Each cel In SrchRng
         If InStr(1, cel.Value, "PD") Then
             cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Decided"
         Else
             cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = "not"        
         End If
     Next cel
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: So, none of your example values would be correct since they don't contain "PD"?

Comment: SORRY!! im tired in the head after a whole day with VBA. The Value is XD and 59

Comment: Also, do you want "Correct" or "decided" to be printed?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried both the function and the single line to my old code that u typed but both return not correct when i do have both 59 and XD in my string.

Comment: Good point - I updated my answer. Should work fine now

Comment: Thank u Callum! I dont know though if u updated ur answer? Still get the not correct input.

Comment: Yes it was updated (see `>0`) and it now works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write it as a function instead? You can use `=CheckValue(H1)` in column `E` for the output your require

```
Function CheckValue(str As String)
    If InStr(str, "XD")>0 And InStr(str, "59")>0 Then
        CheckValue = "Correct"
        Exit Function
    End If
    CheckValue = "Not Correct"
End Function
```

---

This line alone should be enough to make your original code work though (not tested):

```
If InStr(str, "XD")>0 And InStr(str, "59")>0 Then
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the code below, using the `Like` operator and the wild-card `*`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddDashes()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set SrchRng = .Range("A:A") '<-- don't forget to fully qualify your Range    
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value Like "*PD*" And cel.Value Like "*59*" Then
             cel.Offset(0, 3).value = "Decided"
        Else
             cel.Offset(0, 3).value = "not"
        End If
    Next cel    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @CallumDA your'e right, i only now saw the PO's comment below, modified to fit his comment

Comment: THAT WORKED LIKE A CHARM!! Thank u Shai!!